# Boolean Screen Not Returning String

Tags: python

I'm trying to apply what I call an override mapping to a dataframe. Essentially, I'd like the default value to be used from `wkydf` `HistTeamNm` except where my mapping table `mpdf` has a different value. I've used similar logic before and it worked fine.

I've come up with the following:

```
wkydf['ManHistTeam']=wkydf['HistTeamNm']
wkydf.loc[wkydf.UsrIDWkYr.isin(mpdf.UsrIDWkYr),
['ManHistTeam']]=mpdf[['ManHistTeam']]

wkydf['InManMap']='N'
wkydf.loc[wkydf.UsrIDWkYr.isin(mpdf.UsrIDWkYr),['InManMap']]='Y'
```

So

```
wkydf.loc[wkydf.UsrIDWkYr.isin(mpdf.UsrIDWkYr),
['ManHistTeam']]=mpdf[['ManHistTeam']]
```

is currently giving my blanks but in the correct rows, so I'm fairly certain the logic identifying the row to override is working.

Also, when I change the `mpdf[['ManHistTeam']]` to a static `Y`, I get `Y` where I'm expecting. I've also exported the mapping table and the strings are in the expected column. I can't figure out why the logic is returning blanks instead of the string from the mapping table.

Comment: This reads like obfuscated Python.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and desired outputs? [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).